# Status code 200 without response on the server

Tags: python, post, python-requests, postman, put

When I make a `PUT` with a JSON and I receive status code 200 but there is no response on the server shown. When I am making a `PUT` from Postman, everything is fine so, I think that the problem might be in my header:

```
Boxes = [{'X': 2423, 'Y': 532, 'W': 7456, 'H': 2345}]
res = json.dumps(Boxes)

r = requests.put(
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/",
data=json.dumps({"Boxes": res,
                 "Amount": '234'
                 }),
headers={'Authorization': 'Token a50ad9e5ff215abd67028a8bd904a11ac0b1409f',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Vary': 'Accept',
         'Allow': 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS',
         'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY',
         'Content-Length': '140',
         'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
         'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin',
         'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin'},)
print(r.status_code)
```

Headers in Postman:
[image]

Any suggestions on why that might be?

Comment: What headers are Postman using? What is your endpoint expecting?

Comment: The endpoint expects a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I solved the issue by changing authentication details.
I managed to make a request via basic auth:

```
username = ...
password = ... 
response = request.put(url, auth = (username, password)
```

However, I am not sure why this solved the issue

Comment: Postman was doing `Basic` authorization in its headers, you were doing `Bearer`. Sounds like your endpoint doesn't accept token-based auth?

Comment: @wkl, this is weird, because I am accepting an image on .../snippets/1/ via token authentication + in my Django app(server-side): permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly], so it should accept a token auth...